# Looking for link to jQuery CDN link where jquery is exported at alias

Tags: jquery, cdn

Is there a cdn link to the jQuery library where the jQuery library is exported as `$` or some or other alias?

Something like:

```
export default function $() {....
```

This way I could import the jQuery library like:

```
<script type="module">
import {$} from "https://cdnlinkhere";
</script>
```

Comment: You can alias jQuery to any variable you like. The CDN has no bearing on this at all.

Comment: `import {jQuery as $} from ...` See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import